# Show that $f(x)=x^2+2x-1 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_3$. And find the elements of a finite field with 9 elements.

Tags: group-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, cryptography, splitting-field

> Show that $f(x)=x^2+2x-1 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Using this fact construct a finite field $\mathbb{F}_9$ of $9$ elements. If $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$, then find the elements of this field. Also find the discrete logarithms of $(\alpha-1)$ to the base $\alpha$ and of $\alpha$ to the base $(\alpha-1)$.

**My approach:**

Since $f(x)$ has order $2$, it is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ iff it has a root. Since none of $0$ or $1$ or $2$ satisfy $f(x)=0$, so it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Now a field of 9 elements is given by $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{<x^2+2x-1>}$. I'm not sure if this is the field that the question is asking me to construct. Also, I need help with the later part of the question, is the question asking me to find the elements of this field in terms of $\alpha$? If yes, how to do that ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The field contains $0,1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\dotsc$. But you can simplify these: $\alpha^2+2\alpha-1=0$, so $\alpha^2=\alpha+1$; similarly, every power of $\alpha$ can be expressed as $r\alpha+s$ for some $r,s$ in ${\bf Z}_3$.

Comment: The same field with a different polynomial is looked at for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2083368/11619). The difference being that if $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$, then $-\alpha$ is a root of $f(-x)=x^2+x+2$.

Comment: And about calculation of the discrete logarithms. In such a small field you can follow Gerry's suggestion and simply calculate the powers $\alpha^k$, write them in the form $r\alpha+s$, and check when you get $\alpha-1$. The usual change of bases rules on logarithms apply as long as you remember that here the logarithm takes values in the residue class ring $\Bbb{Z}_8$.

Comment: Actually, [in this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/731016/11619) I seem to carry out calculations with exactly the same $\alpha$. Observe that $x^2+2x-1=x^2-x-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a shortcut. In this field we have
$$
\alpha(\alpha-1)=\alpha^2-\alpha=1.
$$
So $\alpha$ and $\alpha-1$ are each others inverses. Hence the two discrete logarithms are both ____ (you fill in the blank, observing the ring the discrete logarithm takes its values in).